# How to use CSS3 within Android WebView?

Tags: android, html, css, webview, transformation

I am developing Android application using HTML5, and I am trying to create rotation of an element using CSS3 transformations, which is the best way to perform this so that app could still run on Android 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android support webkit transformation use

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
```